# JavaScript-ES6 или CoffeeScript поиск ближайшего значения в массиве

Tags: javascript, поиск, ecmascript-6, coffeescript

Необходимо найти ближайший в массиве элемент к заданному. Лучшее решение, которое я нашел на данный момент:

```
var arr= [3,40,90,197], goal= 4;
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= arr.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
      return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
    });
}
```

Какой наилучший способ решить данную задачу?

Comment: в чем определяется _лучшесть_ способа?

Comment: @Grundy
Последние стандарты, эффективность, скорость. Т.е., например, без if, for и т.п. Желательно на CoffeeScript

Comment: Так-то вряд ли будет что-то скорее чем обычный `for`. Хотя бы за счет отсутствия вызова функции для каждого элемента. Кроме того, тернарный оператор - это тот же `if`

Comment: @Grundy
Значит, сравнение каждые следующих элементов в цыкле `for` будет быстрее, чем `.reduce`? (нужно выбрать самое лучшее, что бы порадовать этим моим т.з.)

Comment: Вполне возможно. Все зависит от оптимизаций конкретного браузера. Нельзя однозначно сказать, что _вот этот_ способ быстрее везде. Всегда будет какой-то браузер, в котором будет какая-нибудь оптимизация, позволяющая что-то сделать другим способом быстрее.

Comment: @Grundy
Спасибо! Значит, могу оставить `.reduce`, что бы выглядело эффектней!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш вариант (с использованием `reduce`), но на **ecmascript6**.
В любом случае нужно будет перебрать весь массив, а как это лучше сделать, решать вам :).

```
const abs = Math.abs;
const closest = (a,g) => a.reduce((p,c) => abs(c-g) < abs(p-g) ? c : p);


closest([3, 40, 90, 197], 4);  // 3
closest([1, 2, 9], -5);        // 1
closest([1, 2, 9], 15);        // 9

// document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = closest([3, 40, 90, 197], 4);
```